# I'm confused by passing value to/from pop-up windows

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt

Newbie question, I'm learning PyQt but I'm confused:
I have a main form with buttons, each button connects to a function that opens a different dialog, the dialog executes code that gives a value (it's measuring audio levels via PyAudio). I need to pass that value back to the main form.

At this moment I'm using Global variables but I know this is considered ugly and dangerous (it works though...). I would think that the best way is to pass the variables by reference from the Main form class instance when creating the pop-up dialog, but I'm not sure how to do this, as the method is called by the connect method

```
self.ui.pushButton_SystemCalibration.clicked.connect(self.SystemCalibrationStart)
```

and self has this method:

```
def SystemCalibrationStart(self):

    global SysCalPassed

    self.Diag=SysCalDialog()
    self.Diag.exec_()
```

So how do I get data back from SysCal Dialog (SyscalPassed) to the main form without declaring it global?

Thanks

Comment: No need for any globals. Just access whatever attributes, methods, etc you need after `exec_()` returns (i.e. `value = self.Diag.getValue()`, or whatever).

Comment: That simple eh.. I assumed that after exec_() returns all local variables are out of scope since the object is trashed? Thanks, I'll try.

Comment: Works. Great, thanks